# Gradle/Java application - increase JVM memory size

Tags: java, memory, gradle, jvm

I have Wherehows application written in java/jython and starting it with
 `gradlw build && activator run`.

During the run, due to lot of data - getting memory exception for JVM and crashes.

How can increase JVM memory size and what is the maximum?

Also - how to monitor JVM usage for each step of execution? (e.g. how to print in terminal after every command - what is the current memory usage out of potential maximum)?

Thanks.

Comment: "During the *run*, due to lot of data" - so the gradle part does not appear relevant to your question. You should edit it.

Comment: I wish got more pointers/answers than this..